# reading String out of txt into jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

i want to write a visitor counter for a website and got this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
String datei="pathtotxt/count.txt";
String wert ="";
try{
FileReader eingabestrom= new FileReader(new File(datei));
BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(eingabestrom);
wert=input.readLine();
input.close();

int count=Integer.parseInt(wert);
count++;
FileWriter ausgabestrom=new FileWriter(new File(datei));
BufferedWriter output=new BufferedWriter(ausgabestrom);
output.write(String.valueOf(count));
output.close();
out.println("<h2>Sie sind der ");
out.println(count);
out.println(". Besucher auf unserer Site!</h2>");
}
catch(IOException e) {
out.println("Fehler: "+e);
}
%>

</body></html>
```

In the txt file there's just a zero.
When I open the website, this appears:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: pathtotxt/count.txt (Permission denied)

But I already changed the permission of this file. in the terminal it says -rwxrwxrwx+ so it should be possible to read/write this file. How do I solve this?

Comment: And what about the permissions of the folder(s) `pathtotxt`?

Comment: drwxrwx--x+
do i have to make it the same? so rwxrwxrwx?

Comment: Probably yes. Just try and we'll see `;)`

Answer (score 1):

I think that is better implement this functionality in server side. For example:

- Create a class that in its constructor read the value from file and save it
- This class will have a public method that return the value previously saved (int getCounter()).
- This class will have a public method that increase the value and write it in file, always synchronized.

Then, The JSP code will be as:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="package.of.class.ClassName" %>
<%
ClassName cl = new ClassName();
out.println("<h2>Sie sind der ");
  out.println( cl.getCount());
out.println(". Besucher auf unserer Site!</h2>");
cl.increase();
%>
```

This way, you will improve efficiency rendering JSP and you will not have problems with privileges reading the file

Comment: Classname cannot be resolved to a type, although i used package and stuff. :/